# Stoffresteregal

Tags: german-to-english

What does Stoffresteregal mean in English?

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. If you look for an english word, you might try (after dictionaries) ELL.SE: https://ell.stackexchange.com/ German.SE is only about things in German.

Comment: I think this is a good question that is not a mere dictionary question. Even knowing how to break it up into constituent parts, it is not really all that clear. Searching yields a lot of related pinterest images for Stoffreste, but none really showing one such shelf. I can only assume that it is probably an organizer of sorts in the specific hobby related to making things out of fabric?

Answer (score 1):

"Stoff" means here fabric

"Reste" are leftovers

"Regal" is shelf

Answer (score 0):

I think it is good help to break it up into constituent parts, but maybe a bit of context of where one might encounter such a thing can help.

The best image search results show cases "for storing spools of threads and Stoffreste", and one craft shop offering a discount because their "Stoffresteregal" is "bursting at the seams".

It looks like possibly an organizer for leftovers in sewing hobby or craft - presumably what you get if you are into this hobby, is poorly sized scraps and leftovers that have no obvious use, but may come in handy in some later projects. I don't think there is necessarily an English word for such a specific thing, but I hope you get the idea.